# Why is defining an instance of Choice failing with unknown value?

Tags: typeclass, purescript, profunctor

UPDATE: I'm inlining the code here instead.

I'm trying to define an instance of `Data.Profunctor.Choice` where `right` is defined by calling `left`, but for some reason the compiler complains that `left` is unknown.

```
newtype StateTrans s i o = ST (Tuple s i → Tuple s o)

instance stFunctor ∷ Functor (StateTrans s a) where
  map f (ST st) = ST $ second f <<< st

instance stProfunctor ∷ Profunctor (StateTrans s) where
  dimap f g (ST st) = ST $ second g <<< st <<< second f

instance stChoice ∷ Choice (StateTrans s) where
  left (ST f) = ST lf
    where
    lf (Tuple s (Left a)) = let (Tuple s' b) = f (Tuple s a)
                            in Tuple s' (Left b)
    lf (Tuple s (Right c)) = Tuple s (Right c)
  -- Fails to compile with: Unknown value left
  right f = arr mirror <<< left f <<< arr mirror
    where
    mirror Left x = Right x
    mirror Right x = Left x
```

Probably a silly mistake but I've been looking at my code for so long, I can't figure out what's wrong.

(Of minor importance and unrelated: in the `Right` case for `left`, I have to unwrap and repackage the value so that it type-aligns. Adding a type ascription fails to compile too.)

Strangely enough, I have no problem doing the same for `Strong`, see:

```
instance stStrong ∷ Strong (StateTrans s) where
  first (ST f) = ST ff
    where
    ff (Tuple s (Tuple a c)) = let (Tuple s' b) = f $ Tuple s a
                               in Tuple s' (Tuple b c)
  second f = arr swap <<< first f <<< arr swap
```

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting and where does it point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure as the pasted snippet doesn't include imports, but I suspect you have an import for `Data.Profunctor.Choice (class Choice)` rather than `Data.Profunctor.Choice (class Choice, left, right)`.

Importing a class does not import its members implicitly, even though it is possible to define them in an instance without doing so.

Answer (score 0):

First, to use `arr` you need to declare the `Category` instance for `StateTrans s`:

```
instance stSemigroupoid :: Semigroupoid (StateTrans s) where
  compose (ST f1) (ST f2) = ST $ f1 <<< f2

instance stCategory :: Category (StateTrans s) where
  id = ST $ \x -> x
```

For the second step, I needed to add more type annotations (not sure why they're necessary, but this way the build succeeded):

```
choiceLeft :: forall input output a s. (StateTrans s) input output -> (StateTrans s) (Either input a) (Either output a)
choiceLeft (ST f) = ST lf
  where
    lf (Tuple s (Left a))  = let (Tuple s' b) = f (Tuple s a)
                             in Tuple s' (Left b)
    lf (Tuple s (Right c)) = Tuple s (Right c)

choiceRight :: forall input output t s. (StateTrans s) input output -> (StateTrans s) (Either t input) (Either t output)
choiceRight f = amirror <<< choiceLeft f <<< amirror
  where
    mirror :: forall a b. Either a b -> Either b a
    mirror (Left x)  = Right x
    mirror (Right x) = Left x
    amirror :: forall a b. StateTrans s (Either b a) (Either a b)
    amirror = arr mirror

instance stChoice ∷ Choice (StateTrans s) where
  left  = choiceLeft
  right = choiceRight
```

Note: used `PureScript` version `0.11.7` and `purescript-profunctor` version `3.2.0`.

Comment: Also, I think the missed parentheses around the parameters of `mirror` caused a problem.

Comment: This doesn't doesn't explain the original problem though.

Comment: thanks. I had to import `left` indeed, after that adding a signature to `mirror` to appease the compiler was enough. So just: `mirror :: forall a b. Either b a -> Either a b`